# To get selected tab name from vf page and pass to controller

Tags: apex, visualforce

I need name of the selected tab and pass it to the controller. My code is below:
VF page:


  
    
  
  
        
            
                Summary

```
        </li>
        <li class="slds-tabs_default__item" title="Item Three" style="background:#0070d2;color:White" role="presentation" id="tab-li-default-2">
            <a class="slds-tabs_default__link" href="javascript:void(0);"  role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tab-default-2" id="tab-default-2__item">Incident-Problem</a>

        </li>
        <li class="slds-tabs_default__item" title="Item Three" style="background:#0070d2;color:White" role="presentation" id="tab-li-default-3">
            <a class="slds-tabs_default__link" href="javascript:void(0);" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tab-default-3" id="tab-default-3__item">Availability-Performance</a>

        </li>
        <li class="slds-tabs_default__item" title="Item Three" style="background:#0070d2;color:White" role="presentation" id="tab-li-default-4">
            <a class="slds-tabs_default__link" href="javascript:void(0);" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tab-default-4" id="tab-default-4__item">Service-Finance</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab-default-1" class="slds-tabs_default__content" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-default-1__item">

    </div>
    <div id="tab-default-2" class="slds-tabs_default__content" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-default-2__item">
        <apex:outputPanel >
            <div class="slds-form--stacked">
                <apex:repeat value="{!allQuestions}" var="qPreview" id="aQPreview">
                    <div class="slds-box slds-theme--default">
                        <div class="slds-form-element">
                            <label class="slds-form-element__label slds-text-heading_small">
                                    {!qPreview.orderNumber + ': ' + qPreview.question}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <apex:outputPanel >
                            <apex:selectRadio layout="pageDirection" value="{!qPreview.selectedOption}" >
                                <apex:selectOptions value="{!qPreview.singleOptions}"/>
                            </apex:selectRadio>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                    </div>
                </apex:repeat>
            </div>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-default-3" class="slds-tabs_default__content" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-default-3__item">
        Item Three Content 
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" >

    $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function() {
        $j("#tab-default-2").hide();
        $j("#tab-default-3").hide();
        $j("#tab-default-1").show();
       $j('#tab-default-1__item').click(function(){
           // var str = document.getElementByClassName('{!$Component.myHiddenField}').value;
           // $j('[id$="myHiddenField"]').val('Incident-Problem');
            $j("#tab-li-default-1").css("background-color", "#1589ee");
           $j("#tab-li-default-2").css("background-color", "#0070d2");
            $j("#tab-default-2").hide();
            $j("#tab-default-3").hide();
            $j("#tab-default-1").show();
        });
        $j('#tab-default-2__item').click(function(){
            $j("#tab-default-2").show();
            $j("#tab-li-default-2").css("background-color", "#1589ee");
            $j("#tab-li-default-1").css("background-color", "#0070d2");
            $j("#tab-default-1").hide();
        });
    });
 </script>
    </apex:form>
```

Comment: Can you provide more info on what is not working

Comment: I need to get name of the tab that is selected. Like if I select tab1 then in the controller variable should be set to tab1.

Comment: check my answer to find the solution in above link